# How to preview sizes of widgets in layout before a show()?

Tags: qt

How do I preview what the size of widgets in a window will be after the layout rules are applied, **before** I actually `show()` the widget window? It seems all sizes are 100x30 before that initial `show()` command. How do I go around that?

Comment: MY own widget window class, examines the size of objects and adding dynamic widgets at construction time. I need to measure sizes of how things will look AFTER a layout at that phase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `invalidate()` worked for me.

Notice that if you do the following it would work as asked here (at least it seems to be fine in my code):

```
widget->show();
widget->layout()->invalidate();
widget->hide();
```

This doesn't show the widget on the screen since you don't relinquish control back to the queue until the `hide()` happens. In between, the `invalidate()` computes the correct positions.

Comment: On Qt 5.14 this doesn't work -- the Window flickers between the calls to `show()` and `hide()`.

Comment: @RotsiserMho Interesting... I thought you'd have to hit the event loop for any flickering to happen. Plus even in a multi-thread application the event loop (as far as I know) is not going to be managed but by the main thread.

Answer (score 9):

For me, the following worked:

```
window->layout()->update()
window->layout()->activate()
```

This probably does the same as Alexis' answer but it doesn't require showing-then-hiding the window.

Comment: This did the trick for me too! I was trying to center my window on the screen. It was consistently off until I added those two lines right before I centered the window.

Comment: Sadly this is not working for me on Qt 5.14.

Answer (score 4):

Use QWidget::sizeHint to get the desired size of the top level widget based on the sizeHints of all child widgets and layouts.  Or call QWidget::adjustSize to actually run the layout and resize the entire widget tree.  Note that adjustSize will limit top level windows to 2/3 of the screen so you may not get what you want for large windows.

Answer (score 3):

You could try googling for "qt geometry before show" which shows a thread titled [Force geometry update of hidden widget](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26400-Force-geometry-update-of-hidden-widget) on qtcentre.org forum where you can read *Wysota* answer:

> You can call invalidate() on the
>   layout. It should recalculate itself
>   then. If not then there is this secret
>   attribute that convinces the widget it
>   is being shown and then you should be
>   able to force its layout to
>   recalculate. But try other things
>   first, this is not something very
>   reliable.

and this

> Qt::WA_WState_ExplicitShowHide set to
>   true and Qt::WA_WState_Hidden set to
>   false. Be sure to revert the values
>   (especially the second one) before you
>   actually show the widget on screen.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the various solutions posted by others (`show`&`hide`, `update`&`activate`, `invalidate` and `WA_WState_ExplicitShowHide`&`WA_WState_Hidden`) but none was correct with all the widgets I had to center BEFORE calling `show()` in my application. I spent hours digging and my problem was that incorrect sizes were cached inside **QWidgetItemV2**. A few minutes later I came up with this:

```
for(auto*child:widget->findChildren<QWidget*>()){child->updateGeometry();}
widget->updateGeometry();
```

Answer (score 1):

Under PySide2, this is the solution that ended up being the ticket for my use case:

```
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DontShowOnScreen, True)
    self.show()
    self.layout().invalidate()
    self.hide()
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DontShowOnScreen, False)
```

This is effectively the same as the accepted answer. However, omitting the changes to the `WA_DontShowOnScreen` attribute would cause a window flicker on first show.