# Remove scrollbar to show full table

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qtablewidget

I have a scrollview to which I dynamically add QTableWidgets. However, the QTables themselves also have scrollbars and therefore don't show the full table. Is there a way to disable the scroll bar so that the table always gets shown in full?

[image]

EDIT: I added

```
    self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
```

As suggested. The scroll bar does disappear, but it still only shows the partial tables (Ican scroll with hovering iverthe table and using the mouse wheel, still). The code for the Widget is below

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class MdTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, depth, *args):

        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.hheaders = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]
        self.depth = depth
        self.bids = data
        self.setData()

    def setData(self):

        self.setRowCount(self.depth)
        self.setColumnCount(5)

        for i in xrange(self.depth):
            if len(self.data) > i:
                d1= QTableWidgetItem(str(self.data[i][0]))
                d2= QTableWidgetItem(str(self.data[i][1]))
                self.setItem(i, 1, d1)
                self.setItem(i, 2, d2)

        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.hheaders)
        self.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to delete the Scrollbar you must use:

```
{QtableWidget}.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
{QtableWidget}.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
```

If you want to show the expanded `QTableWidget`, add this to the end of the `setData()` method:

```
self.setMaximumSize(self.getQTableWidgetSize())
self.setMinimumSize(self.getQTableWidgetSize())
```

and define `getQTableWidgetSize(self)` like this:

```
def getQTableWidgetSize(self):
    w = self.verticalHeader().width() + 4  # +4 seems to be needed
    for i in range(self.columnCount()):
        w += self.columnWidth(i)  # seems to include gridline (on my machine)
    h = self.horizontalHeader().height() + 4
    for i in range(self.rowCount()):
        h += self.rowHeight(i)
    return QtCore.QSize(w, h)
```

[image]

**Note:**
The function `getQTableWidgetSize` is a conversion of the code in C ++ to python of the following post: [How to determine the correct size of a QTableWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766633/how-to-determine-the-correct-size-of-a-qtablewidget)

Comment: from PySide.QtCore import *

self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)


I added this to the class that inherits QTableWidget. But it does not change anything

Comment: @chrise self is QTableWidget?

Comment: yes. It s in this class
class DataTable(QTableWidget):

Comment: actually, I was mistaken. The scrollbar disappeared, but it still shows the reduced data, not the full table

Comment: @chrise 
I guess what you want is if there is more information displayed by QTableWidget the font size decreases.

Comment: Is there another way. That would render text very unreadable as currently it displays two rows and I want 5 to 10, so text would be tiny

Comment: I tried using resize, both from inside the QtableWidget as self.resize(.,.) as well as from the outside, w.resize(.,.) but this seems to get completely ignored

Comment: @chrise 
Can you show me the image that comes with my suggestion?