# How to let QTableWidge adjust size to its content

Tags: qt

The followin code creates a QTableWidget with some content.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    m_tbl = new QTableWidget;
    qDebug() << m_tbl->sizeHint(); // output "QSize(256, 192)"
    qDebug() << m_tbl->sizePolicy(); 
    /* above line outputs "QSizePolicy(horizontalPolicy = QSizePolicy::Policy(Expanding), verticalPolicy = QSizePolicy::Policy(Expanding))" */
    m_tbl->setRowCount(4);
    m_tbl->setColumnCount(2);
    m_tbl->horizontalHeader()->setVisible(false);
    m_tbl->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
    m_tbl->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem(QString("0,0")));
    m_tbl->setItem(0,1,new QTableWidgetItem(QString("0,1")));
    m_tbl->setItem(1,0,new QTableWidgetItem(QString("1,0")));
    m_tbl->setItem(1,1,new QTableWidgetItem(QString("1,1")));
    m_tbl->setItem(2,0,new QTableWidgetItem(QString("2,0")));
    m_tbl->setItem(2,1,new QTableWidgetItem(QString("2,1")));
    m_tbl->setItem(3,0,new QTableWidgetItem(QString("3,0")));
    m_tbl->setItem(3,1,new QTableWidgetItem(QString("3,1")));
    m_tbl->adjustSize(); // not making any difference
    m_tbl->show();
}
```

The problem is the window size is larger than the content - please see the image below. How could one let the window adjust its size according to its content in this case?

[image: Window size is larger than its content]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`adjustSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#adjustSize) takes size hint and policy into account. Since your size hint is valid, it will use the size hint.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. Basically the solution is to calculate the width and height yourself, from the columns and rows ort he headers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766633/how-to-determine-the-correct-size-of-a-qtablewidget

Comment: Check Zbyněk Winkler's answer in that post

Comment: @Ngoc Minh Nguyen Thanks for the information. For my case, I just needed the "length" part in the answer you pointed out, since my vertical/horizontal headers are hidden.